# How to append multiple scripts in one time? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js";
script.type='text/javascript';
var done = false;
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
            done = true;
    promptForUserEntries();
}
};  
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

This inject one script in the first Head. I have three other scripts and I insert theme by the same way, now I'm looking for how to insert multiple script in a Tag in one time.

Thank you

Comment: Just combine the scripts in one and then you have them in once script tag.

Comment: You could always use something like [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var scripts = ["/path/to/script.js", "/path/to/script2.js"];

for (index = 0; index < scripts.length; ++index) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = scripts[index];
    script.type='text/javascript';
    var done = false;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
            done = true;
            //promptForUserEntries();
        }
    };  
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

This will loop through your array of scripts to append, and append them

Comment: I think this is the closest  answer to Phiber question. :)

Comment: Thank you !. since I have also a links to inject, i have adapted your solution to my case. Great day for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified solution based on Ole's answer. It allows for both scripts with src tags and script blocks - Useful for loading Google Analytics code after cookie consent, for example.

```
/**
 * Append a block of script code to the head
 * Code can contain scripts with src attribute
 * and script blocks
 */
function appendScriptBlocks (code) {

    let tempEl = document.createElement('div')
    tempEl.innerHTML = code
    let scripts = tempEl.getElementsByTagName('script')

    for (let index = 0; index < scripts.length; ++index) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type= 'text/javascript';

        if(scripts[index].src) {
            script.src = scripts[index].src;
        }
        else {
            script.innerHTML = scripts[index].innerHTML
            eval(scripts[index].innerHTML)
        }
        
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think if you use `script.text = scripts[index].innerHTML` instead `script.innerHTML = scripts[index].innerHTML`, there is no need to call `eval`